# devpi - how to get "root/<package>/json" served

Tags: devpi

my goal is to install python-packages on a micropython-device. Anyway I got the devpi-server to run and and upload a package.

What I could not achieve is, that the devpi-server delivers something like you get from:
https://micropython.org/pi/micropython-pystone_lowmem/json

Accessing the above url is, how "upip" gets its package information.

So I'm new to Pypy-server and devpi-server and this might be a trivial question, anyway I get stuck at this point.

Thank you for any help in advance, Axel.

Comment: Still struggling with this issue:

I modified upip so that it requests "application/json" ... anyway the response has so many (irrelevant) information, that ujson.load() gives up (probably not enough memory).

What is needed in devpi is https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIJSON
What is missing; A tutorial how to make and debug a very simple devpi-plugin.

Any responses are highly welcome!
Axel.

Comment: Take a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/fschulze/077320ab51f8ae91381d5e7faa0ac647 It doesn't do any checking though, so there may be a few possibilities for exceptions. You can build from there by taking a look at what devpi-server and devpi-web do to filter the list down to for example the latest versions or only specific kind of releases.

Comment: @fschulze, thanks for the very quick response, I briefly tested it with curl and get a NotSerializable exception. A quick look at the data uncovered that in the Info block are a few SeqViewReadonly([]) objects which are probably the reason for this.

TypeError: SeqViewReadonly([]) is not JSON serializable

To get further, a quick and dirty filter to replace SeqViewReadonly with empty strings, will do it for now. 
Thank you for the help, I will come back to this thread later.

Comment: I have updated the gist with a call to ``get_mutable_deepcopy`` which is meant for that. I hope I didn't break it, I didn't test the change.

Comment: This change works, the next challenge is now to add the port number to url:

 {'0.0.1': [{'url': 'http://localhost/testuser/dev/+f/333/27252594686a5/micropython-iot-utils-0.0.1.tar.gz'}]

shall be localhost:3141. 

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It produces correct URLs for me. Do you access devpi-server directly, or do you have a proxy or port redirect in front? Look for the ``--outside-url`` option and/or the ``X-Outside-URL`` header in the documentation if you do.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that with curl the returned URL is correct and the file can be downloaded, so the problem is probably in upip.
How to proceed with the gist? 
If I get upip to work, I will come back to here and then it can go as a plugin to pypi. If your time is limited, I also can do the packaging and maintenance.

Comment: I've just added a MIT LICENSE file like the rest of devpi. Feel free to package it and put it on PyPI.

Comment: Will package devpi-json the next days. Shall we make a Repo or just take the files from the Gist and reference devpi homepage?
Finally it succeeded, there was just some tweeks in upip.py which I will feed to the micropython guys. Many thanks again, Axel

Comment: I think this should go into a repo. I named the package ``devpi-json-info`` in ``setup.py``, because I think ``devpi-json`` is too vague.
Glad it works for you!

Comment: I think the repo should go inside the devpi group, Or is it OK if I put it along my repos and make it public? For https://github.com/devpi I have no permissions since I'm not a member.

Comment: Just put it along your repos, I have some plugins under fschulze as well.

Comment: It took a while but now the package made it at least to https://test.pypi.org/project/devpi-json-info

Comment: Now package is at central pypi.org

Comment: There seems to be no like button for comments, so: Congrats!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two steps needed, to get micropython packages installed via devpi-server.

1st:
Thanks to the support from @fschulze from the devpi-server project  a Gist is provided gist.github.com/fschulze/077320ab51f8ae91381d5e7faa0ac647 which adds /json capbility to devpi-server.

Update: You can install devpi-json-info with `pip install devpi-json-info`
from https://pypi.org/project/devpi-json-info/

2nd:
upip.py needs a patch to support port numbers:

Update 2020-10-20: The patch below has made it in the micropython repository, thanks to @dpgeorge, [56e0932](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/commit/56e0932485af51ec175c8f43432eee67d657b334)

Update 2020-10-08: added the patch below as [PR:6521](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/6521)

```
 --- upip.py.orig   2020-09-01 21:14:20.410287796 +0200
 +++ upip.py    2020-09-11 21:54:03.567011061 +0200
 @@ -129,7 +129,11 @@
  
      proto, _, host, urlpath = url.split("/", 3)
      try:
 -        ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, 443, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)
 +        port = 443
 +        if ":" in host:
 +            host, port = host.split(":")
 +            port = int(port)
 +        ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)
      except OSError as e:
          fatal("Unable to resolve %s (no Internet?)" % host, e)
      # print("Address infos:", ai)
 @@ -147,7 +151,7 @@
                  warn_ussl = False
  
          # MicroPython rawsocket module supports file interface directly
 -        s.write("GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n" % (urlpath, host))
 +        s.write("GET /%s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s:%s\r\n\r\n" % (urlpath, host, port))
          l = s.readline()
          protover, status, msg = l.split(None, 2)
          if status != b"200":
```